# Does method call in log is optional?

Tags: contract-development, transactions

Let me explain my question in detail.

let's say we are gonna deploy a smart contract that would invoke a certain function in an official contract (e.g function bark in contract dog) Link: https://github.com/makerdao/dss/blob/liq-2.0/src/dog.sol

but, I won't emit it, so there is nothing shown on logs, and if anyone wanna trace what I have done he/she will get nothing, but my contract could still work as expected. Can I do it like this?

Or I change another way to ask, Does function in the contract posted by MakerDao(the link I mentioned before) all need to be emitted when someone invokes them? Is it possible in Ethereum I could hide some information in a transaction log so that no one could trace what I've done?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent that a contract you call emits events that are defined in their contract code.

In general it will be hard to completely hide what you do in a transaction call, since any transaction can be traced and therefore it is possible to check what contracts have been called and what state has been changed by the transaction.

This information is available on Etherscan [e.g. this transaction](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x2c1d9e08116be060bdc4f8ee5b57b571bb30a2a4dc99a201a1b4185ca2adde73&type=parity) and there are multiple platforms to perform in-depth analysis of transactions (e.g. [Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x2c1d9e08116be060bdc4f8ee5b57b571bb30a2a4dc99a201a1b4185ca2adde73))

Comment: Thank you very much, the website you provided is really useful! May I ask you do you know how to get the raw trace from Ethereum? I mean is there any way we can get the trace on our computer by statements like `trace=Web3.get_raw_trace(tx_hash)`?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer (end 2022), there have been some advances since the user asked a question. Yes, it is true that you cannot prevent [transaction traces such as this](https://library.dedaub.com/transactions/Ethereum/B718E6CD65EF15F8DF967B009E5E794CAB87B11810039A6E01F30BB30F85C56C) from emitting events, however there are privacy solutions in the pipeline, using zero knowledge proofs or otherwise that would not reveal the real address that's originating the transaction. An example is the Railgun protocol.